# How do I see what kits my team is using?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

The "Select Class" menu shows how many people are what class (Assault, Support, etc.), but how do I see, for example, how many Medics or Engineers we have?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear there is any sort of in-game display showing whether they're Medic or Engineer.

The only two options I've found are to ask my team directly, or go into spectator mode and cycle through until I see for myself. It's a pain, but it's better than bringing something you don't need into the fight.